# How to inject all classes implementing the same generic interface in the constructor using StructureMap?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, dependency-injection, structuremap

I have a bunch of data fetchers which all has the almost same signature. The only thing that differs is the return type. The return type is specified as T:

I have this interface:

```
public interface IDataFetcher<T>
{
    T FetchData(MyObject data);
}
```

Next I have a about 10 implementations of this interface. In de the calling code I want to do something like this:

```
public class FetchCommandHandler
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<IDataFetcher<T>> _fetchers;

    public FetchCommandHandler(IEnumerable<IDataFetcher<T>> fetchers) // this of course does not work
    {
        _fetchers = fetchers;
    }

    public MyResult Handle()
    {
        var myObj = new MyObject(); // get object from database

        foreach(var fetcher in _fetchers)
        {
           var result = fetcher.FetchData(myObj);
           // do something with result
        }
    }
}
```

So, in the end, what I want is not have to inject each `DataFetcher<T>` implementation in the constructor. I am looking for a way to retreive all the registrations of `IDataFetcher<T>` from StructureMap.

I am open for every other design that achieves the same result, ie, not inject each implementation in the constructor.

Comment: Because the return type of the fetcher differ, you need to show show (and explain) what you are doing with the results from your fetchers. Your foreach loop now assumes the type is the same, and it assumes you are able to process all results identically, but their different return type implies that you have different processing for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What we can do is introduce another interface for return type and all the types that will be returned will implement it.

Define an interface :

```
public interface IData
{
}

public interface IDataFetcher<T> where T : IData
{
    T FetchData(MyObject data);
}
```

As an example a type that would be returned:

```
public class FooData : IData
{
}
```

and it's DataFetcher implementation will look like:

```
public class FooDataFetcher : IDataFetcher<FooData>
{
     public FooData FetchData(MyObject data)
     {
       // logic here and return instance of FooData
     }
}
```

Now what we can do is define the Handler class something like:

```
public class FetchCommandHandler
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<IDataFetcher<IData>> _fetchers;

    public FetchCommandHandler(IEnumerable<IDataFetcher<IData>> fetchers) // this of course does not work
    {
        _fetchers = fetchers;
    }

    public MyResult Handle()
    {
        var myObj = new MyObject(); // get object from database

        foreach(var fetcher in _fetchers)
        {
           var result = fetcher.FetchData(myObj);
           // do something with result
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I understand the idea, but I don't get it to work in SM. I'm doing this to register the fetchers: `scan.Assembly("name_of_the_containing_assembly");
scan.ConnectImplementationsToTypesClosing(typeof(IDataFetcher<>));`

Comment: not sure about syntax of SM but this should help to register

Comment: After hours of trying I finally figured it out. I didn't specify the `out` keyword in `IDataFetcher<T>`, so that must be `IDataFetcher<out T>`. Makes sense because we're dealing with an interface here and not a concrete type.

Comment: @Martijn finally it worked for you, did you used `IData` in your solution ?

Comment: Yes I did, otherwise I can't inject `IEnumerable<T>` into my constructor :)